# If time is more than X and less than Y, between daybreaks?

Tags: bash, date, if-statement, time

In one of my loops, I've made my Bash script do things depending on the time:

```
if [ $(date +%k%M) -ge 2200 ] && [ $(date +%k%M) -lt 2300 ] ; then echo "Betwen 22 and 23!"; fi
```

However, I just got a problem I didn't expect (although I should have). The if doesn't work when 23:59 becomes 00:00.

```
if [ $(date +%k%M) -ge 2359 ] && [ $(date +%k%M) -lt 200 ] ; then CURRENTFOLDER="$TARGETFOLDER/$BLOCK1"; fi
```

200 is numerically less than 2359, but 02:00 is later than 23:59.

What can I do?

Comment: `&&`  => `||` would do it..

Comment: I'm sorry, not following you… Can you give me an example? Thanks!

Comment: A time  `< 200` OR a time `>= 2359` are both valid for you if you cross midnight, so instead of having to have _both_ be true (`&&`), it's enough to have _either_ of them to be true (`||`).

Answer (score 4):

Converting to seconds makes this type of 'arithmetic' much easier and more reliable. Use date's '--date=' option to specify that next day's window:

```
date --date="Today HH:MM" +"%s"
date --date="+1 day HH:MM" +"%s"
```

Also, for simplicity's sake, call the current time once and use it for comparison :)

```
NOW=$(date +"%s")
```

Examples:

```
(( ${NOW} >= $(date --date="Today 22:00" +"%s") )) && (( ${NOW} < $(date --date="Today 23:00" +"%s") ))

(( ${NOW} >= $(date --date="Today 23:59" +"%s") )) && (( ${NOW} < $(date --date="+1 day 02:00" +"%s") ))
```

You can also use seconds field to do file modification comparisons, etc., using output from 'find' or 'stat'.

Depending on how many actions you take, you'd be better using combining into a case statement.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, great answer. I'm just a little confused on how to best do it on the end user side. If they simply have 4 digits to choose from for each time, and I want to let them be able to choose 23:00-01:00, how do I solve that without forcing them to specify "today" and "tomorrow"?

Comment: If you must use a 4-digit start/end time, you could evaluate the provided end time using `ENDTIME="01:00"`... `[[ ${ENDTIME} == 0[0-9]:?? ]]`. If true, use tomorrow's date, otherwise use today's.

Another way would be to prompt the user for both the date and time. Start time `07/19 23:00` instead of `23:00`, End time `07/20 01:00` instead of `01:00`.

Lastly, you could use a duration based logic. Define start time as `07/19 23:00` with a duration of 2 hours.. set duration as `DUR="2"`, then calculate end time with `date --date='+'${DUR}' hours'` -- this would move into the next day by design.